# JavaScript script tag inside php code

Tags: php, javascript

I have one page (parent) which opens a second page via popup (child)

On the second page I have the following PHP code which gets the value of an HTML element from the parent page:

```
 $var=print_r("<script type='text/javascript'>var x=window.opener.document.getElementsByName('name1');document.write(x[0].value)</script>",true);
```

When I echo the variable `$var` I get exactly what I expect. Thus:

```
echo "test=" . $test;
```

... prints for example "Expenses" on the page.

So far so good.

The problem is when I try to write this variable to a file like:

```
$f=fopen("/mylog.txt","w+");
fwrite($f, $test);
fclose($f);
```

... then , instead of the actual value of `$test` (e.g. Expenses),

I get the whole script tag in my logfile, thus:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var x=window.opener.document.getElementsByName('name1');document.write(x[0].value)</script>
```

Assuming that `print_r` with 'true' parameter returns the value to my `$test` variable, why is it writing the exact script tag to the logfile?

How can I overcome this?

Comment: that's because the javascript is interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Why on earth would you `$var = print_r('string', true);` a string? That acheives precisely nothing over `$var = 'string';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `echo` the value to a browser, it will run the JavaScript and display the result.

When you save it to a file, the JavaScript isn't executed.

In both cases, the full script is output, but the browser is actually running the script, whereas your text editor won't.

Answer (score 1):

Send your data which is on the client to the server.  You can use Ajax (shown below) or a form.

```
$.post('myPHPfile.php',{name:window.opener.document.getElementsByName('name1')});
```

myPHPfile.php

```
$test=$_POST['name'];
$f=fopen("/mylog.txt","w+");
fwrite($f, $test);
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK , I accomplished the desired result by altering the url-string which calls the 2nd page with an extra variable (the desired one) and then , via $_GET , I retrieve this value and can print it without problems to my logfile.

Many thanks guys to all of you for the quick responses :)

Comment: Since you are storing the value, post is more suitable.